# Remotely execute windows 10 command from Linux box

Tags: c#, linux, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I'm looking for a way to use a Linux box (specifically a RasPi) to control a Windows 10 computer on the same local network. Generally I'd like to be able to use the RasPi to execute any custom script on the Windows machine, but the standard use case will be opening up NetFlix and applying NetFlix media controls (play/pause, volume, etc).

So far I've looked into using UnifiedRemote (which seems to require that the Android app be installed on the machine before you can use the API), and WinExe (which doesn't seem to work with Windows 10).

Short of SSHing commands from the RasPi and writing my own listener in C#, how can I send commands from my RasPi to my Win 10 machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just so lucky that Microsoft has open sourced PowerShell and made it cross platform. Now you can run PowerShell at Linux side and remotely manage a Windows machine,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/08/18/powershell-on-linux-and-open-source-2/